# Windows Server 2008 Data Center vs Standard Overhead

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

We are moving to virtual servers with Hyper-v and have MS W2K8R2 Data Center on the hosting servers.  My question is there any reason to use Standard vs Data Center for a virtual machine that shouldn't need Data Center functionality like a print server?  If I use Data Center for all my virtual machines and not enable any unneeded roles or features is there any difference in processing, memory, etc. overhead that Standard wouldn't require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in (CPU/memory/...) footprint between Standard and Data Center if the same roles and features are installed.

Comment: That is what I hoped would be the case.